# PHP, Zend, Facebook Share (Change the content)

Tags: php, facebook, zend-framework

How can I change the content of my facebook share option? my web app is written on PHP with Zend Framework. I want to change the content of the facebook share option instead of the description that was already been in the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use fb social plugin, it reads the open graph tags.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
```

You can set those in zend by using in controller

```
$this->view->headMeta()->setProperty('og:description','asdasdasd'); 
        $this->view->headMeta()->setProperty('og:title',"title here");
        $this->view->headMeta()->setProperty('og:image',"url");
```

if you dont want to use that open graph tags,

**Creating Your Own Share URL**

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=titlehere&p[url]=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yoururlhere.com&p[summary]=yours description
```

Open that URL in a browser, when user click share icon/link.

Btw, share is deprecated.
FYI: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

Comment: you mean its going to be like this
    <a name="fb_share" type="button" share_url="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sadtrombone.com%2F&t=Sad%20Trombone"> Share on facebook</a>

Comment: yes if you use sharer link <a name="fb_share" href="http://facebook.com/…; Share on facebook</a>

Comment: with the meta tags for zend framework that you've edited. I already have a description from the website also title. so is it possible if I put this also? will this ruin the descriptions?

Comment: it wont ruin title but it will ruin desciption. I have updated it now $this->view->headMeta()->setProperty('og:description','asdasdasd');

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12992/discussion-between-newbie-and-venu)

Answer (score 0):

**FB Share description**:
You can control the exact title, description, and thumbnail that Facebook Share uses by adding the following meta tags to the  element in your page:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
```

please read more [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/):

regards.

Comment: take a look to Para: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/   Titled 'Basic Tags' and Read it carefully.

Comment: @newbie,you can add this in your layout.phtml, if you are using zend layout.